# Can I define table relationships in this situation to get cascade deletes to flow even though the underlying data types overlap?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I am trying to work out how to properly describe a set of database table relationships in a way that preserves both the hierarchy I have defined, as well as the cascading deletes I need.  What follows is the set of tables in question, as well as the configurations where important:

```
public enum LocationType
{
    Location,
    Biosolid,
    BioSite
}

public class Location
{
    private Int32 _id;
    public Int32 ID
    {
        get => _id;
        set => SetProperty(ref _id, value, () => ID);
    }

    private LocationType _locationType;
    public LocationType LocationType
    {
        get => _locationType;
        set => SetProperty(ref _locationType, value, () => LocationType);
    }

    private String _name;
    public String Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set => SetProperty(ref _name, value, () => Name);
    }
}

public class LocationConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Location>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Location> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Location");
        builder.HasDiscriminator(x => x.LocationType)
            .HasValue(LocationType.Location)
            .HasValue<BioSite>(LocationType.BioSite)
            .HasValue<Biosolid>(LocationType.Biosolid);
        builder.Property(x => x.LocationType).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(x => x.Name).HasMaxLength(30).IsRequired();
        builder.HasIndex(x => x.Name).IsUnique();
    }
}


public class BioSite : Location
{
    private BiosolidsSiteType _biosolidsSiteType;
    public BiosolidsSiteType BiosolidsSiteType
    {
        get => _biosolidsSiteType;
        set => SetProperty(ref _biosolidsSiteType, value, () => BiosolidsSiteType);
    }

    private Double? _siteArea;
    public Double? SiteArea
    {
        get => _siteArea;
        set => SetProperty(ref _siteArea, value, () => SiteArea);
    }
}

public class Biosolid : Location
{
    private BiosolidsType _biosolidsType;
    public BiosolidsType BiosolidsType
    {
        get => _biosolidsType;
        set => SetProperty(ref _biosolidsType, value, () => BiosolidsType);
    }
}


public class BioApplication
{
    private Int32 _id;
    public Int32 ID
    {
        get => _id;
        set => SetProperty(ref _id, value, () => ID);
    }

    private DateTime _dateTime;
    public DateTime DateTime
    {
        get => _dateTime;
        set => SetProperty(ref _dateTime, value, () => DateTime);
    }

    public Int32 BioSiteID { get; set; }
    public BioSite BioSite { get; set; }

    public Int32 BiosolidID { get; set; }
    public Biosolid Biosolid { get; set; }
}

public class BioApplicationConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<BioApplication>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<BioApplication> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("BioApplication");
        builder.Property(x => x.DateTime).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(x => x.BioSiteID).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(x => x.BiosolidID).IsRequired();
        builder.HasIndex(x => x.BioSiteID).IsUnique(false);
        builder.HasIndex(x => x.BiosolidID).IsUnique(false);
        builder.HasOne(x => x.BioSite).WithMany().HasForeignKey(y => y.BioSiteID).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        builder.HasOne(x => x.Biosolid).WithMany().HasForeignKey(y => y.BiosolidID).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }
}
```

I am using Entity Framework Core 5.0.2, and targeting .NET (Core) 5.0 while writing in WPF.

The problem occurs at runtime as the database is being created, and I get this error message:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Introducing FOREIGN KEY
> constraint 'FK_BioApplication_Location_BiosolidID' on table
> 'BioApplication' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify
> ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN
> KEY constraints.

Having read up on this, I understand what it wants.  The part I don't understand is why it does not seem to respect the `Discriminator` I defined and know that only one should be triggering the deletion.  If it is simply because all it cares about is that they both resolve to `Location` I can understand that.  Although that makes me question the usefulness of TPH, but I suppose that's another matter.

So the question is: can I configure my tables or fluent API configs to get everything I want out of this?

Comment: The database doesn't know about inheritance. It only knows there are two FK's from table `BioApplication` to table `Location`: multiple cascade paths.

Comment: Also, what is "everything I want out of this"? For example, if a `BioApplication` points to two different locations, one location is deleted, what should happen? Anyway, the answer will always be simple: you have to take control yourself, you can't fight the database limitation.

Comment: @GertArnold I'm coming to that same conclusion.  I guess I was hoping for some EF magic in between to manage it, but I see your point that SQL Server simply cannot allow it to be created.  As for the requirements:  benefiting from cascade delete automation without losing the hierarchy.  You see, I expected answers like "make them separate tables".

Comment: Didn't you give yourself the answer here? :) What happens if you use separate tables?

Comment: @KaiHartmann Bluntly:  a lot of unnecessary duplication.  I stripped the definition of `Location` down a lot for the sake of keeping the amount of code in this example down.  The inherited "tables" have a field or two each, so they would all then need to duplicate all of the information in the base table.  That's to say nothing of what then happens in code when I have to separately treat each on individually where I could have used the base class in a lot of shared code.  TPH is nice for its usage benefits.